# sudo: a password is required ansible-playbook

Tags: docker, ansible, sudo, ansible-2.x

I have an ansible playbook which installs docker. It looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: local
  connection: local
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: add docker's key
      apt_key:
        keyserver: hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80
        id: 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D

    - name: add deb repo
      file: path=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list state=touch

    - name: register apt sources
      lineinfile: dest="/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list" line="{{item}}"
      with_items:
      - "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty main"

    - name: install docker-engine
      apt: name=docker-engine state=present update-cache=yes force=yes
```

The problem is that when I run this playbook on my localhost I get an error:

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 1}
```

So what parts of this playbook may cause such an error and how can I change them?

Comment: The `become`/`become_user` is causing Ansible to `sudo` up to the `root` user to perform each of these steps.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I thought it was more like a replacement for sudo:yes

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to use [`--ask-become-pass`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/become.html#command-line-options) with your command line. You should then be prompted for the password.

Comment: I have tried that. But I am not sure that it is a good solution for long-term

Comment: @Cassie Well the other solution implying a password would be to somehow store the password which wouldn't necessarly be better.
Perhaps you'd be able to find some trick to store the password in a vault file but you'd need to enter an other password to unlock the vault file anyway.

If you expected a different workflow than password use you should describe it in your question.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help!

Comment: I think long-term best practice is now store password in the vault. --ask-become-pass is now deprecated, too.